# Why do VMs used by my Dataflow jobs say "in use by"?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

The Dataflow Service ​now ​￼uses GCE's [Managed Instance Groups](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/) to organize the [compute resources exercised by your Dataflow jobs](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/service/dataflow-service-desc#workers). ​

Answer (score 0):

The Dataflow Service ​now ​￼uses GCE's [Managed Instance Groups](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/) to organize the [compute resources exercised by your Dataflow jobs](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/service/dataflow-service-desc#workers). ​